# Using axios.all() and axios.spread() "can't find variable" method error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, referenceerror

I am trying to create a program that runs multiple axios requests to get data for a chart, and waits for them all to finish before pulling that data into a chart. This is some of my current code:

```
minBugs() {
  return (
    axios({
      responseType: 'json',
      auth: {
        username: '<username>',
        password: '<password>'
      }
    })
    .get('<url>'));
}

normBugs() {
  return (axios({
    responseType: 'json',
    auth: {
      username: '<username>',
      password: '<password>'
    }
  }).get('<url>'));
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.all([minBugs(), normBugs()])
    .then(axios.spread(function(a, b) {
      //manipulate data 
    }))
    .catch(message => console.log('Axios exception: ', message));
}
```

When I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: minBugs
```

Any ideas why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since the other parts of your component is missing we can't see what is going on here, but you are using `componentDidMount`, then this component should be a class component. So, you need to use your functions with `this`.

```
componentDidMount() {
      axios.all([this.minBugs(), this.normBugs()])
      .then(axios.spread(function (a, b) { 
         //manipulate data 
      }))
      .catch(message => console.log('Axios exception: ', message));
}
```